# Android NDK find dynamic link : unable to debug library

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-ndk, gdb

I have a project that compiles, loads and runs in the android device nicely. When I call the gdb server it also works fine. Then, when I call the gdb client to run through with breakpoints is when the message appears:

```
Error while mapping shared library sections:
/system/bin/linker: No such file or directory.

libandroid.so: No such file or directory.
liblog.so: No such file or directory.
libEGL.so: No such file or directory.
libOpenSLES.so: No such file or directory.
libGLESv2.so: No such file or directory.
libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so: No such file or directory.
...
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code
warning: shared library handler failed to enable breakpoint
```

This is my current Android.mk file, for the case some additional setup might be missing:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LS_CPP=$(subst $(1)/,,$(wildcard $(1)/*.cpp))
APP_MODULES := callbacks
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
APP_OPTIM:= debug

LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -DRAPIDXML_NO_EXCEPTIONS
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -g
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -ggdb
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -O1

LOCAL_MODULE:=app3D
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call LS_CPP,$(LOCAL_PATH))
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -landroid -llog -lEGL -lOpenSLES -lGLESv2
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue png
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += /jni

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
$(call import-module,libpng)
```

Any suggestion about what is the reason for such weird error and how to get rid of it?

All comments and hints are deeply appreciated and welcome.

Comment: Dude, we just got a debugger in the NDK ;) don't force it.. I think the GDB will not attach to a dynamic lib. At least not now, hopefully soon..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ndk-gdb` instead of standard `gdb`. Launch it from your project root directory. Consider using `--verbose` option if you'd like to see what `ndk-gdb` is doing.
You must add this line to your `AndroidManifest.xml` also:

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

For instance, mine looks like:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:debuggable="true" >
```

your application.mk should define

```
APP_OPTIM := debug
```

With this you don't have to add `-g` to your compiler flags, ndk-build will do so automatically.

Comment: Unable to create a debugger engine of the type "No engine"